# Love2d "bad argument #2 to 'draw' (Quad expected, got nil)"

Tags: lua, love2d

I am currently trying to make a flappy bird copy and I am having trouble when attempting to spawn in pipes (when a pipe should spawn I get the following error: "bad argument #2 to 'draw' (Quad expected, got nil)").

The functions that are causing the problem are the following (they are located in three different classes):

```
Pipe = Class{}

local PIPE_IMAGE = love.graphics.newImage('FlappyBirdPipe.png')

PIPE_SCROLL = -60

PIPE_WIDTH = 20
PIPE_HEIGHT = 160

function Pipe:init(orientation, y)
    self.x = VIRTUAL_WIDTH
    self.y = y

    self.width = PIPE_IMAGE:getWidth()
    self.height = PIPE_HEIGHT

    self.orientation = orientation
end

function Pipe:render()
    love.graphics.draw(PIPE_IMAGE, self.x, 
        (self.orientation == 'top' and self.y + PIPE_HEIGHT or self.y),
        0, 1, (self.orientation == 'top' and -1 or 1))
end
```

```
function PipePair:update(dt)
    if self.x > -PIPE_WIDTH then
        self.x = self.x - PIPE_SCROLL * dt
        self.pipes['lower'].x = self.X
        self.pipes['upper'].x = self.x
    else
        self.remove = true
    end
end
```

If anything is unclear or I have left out some vital information I am more than glad to give more information (I am new to Stack Overflow so I am not really sure how everything here works).

(I am using love2d version 11.3 in vscode)

Edit: I pinpointed the error to how I update the self.x in the Pipe class from the PipePair class' update function. Somehow this altering of self.x seems to make it nil.

Comment: have you tried printing the args you are passing to draw before calling it, what do these arg show when printed? also without information on how a `pipe` is defined this would be very hard to answer. Please share what version of `love2d` you are using.

Comment: I have now added what version I am using and the full Pipe class. (note that Pipe and PipePair are two different classes)

Comment: I tried printing self.x and self.y and it seems like self.y is defined but that self.x is nil. Also I tried setting self.x to an integer instead of VIRTUAL_WIDTH which still caused an error.

Comment: can you show where you call `Pipe:init`, right now it is unclear how your `pipe`s are being created the `init` function you have shown only acts on an existing pipe(or the Pipe Class as a whole) it does not create a new `pipe`. I would also suggest creating a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) this might help lead you to the cause of your problem on its own, it can also eliminate the need of this back and forth in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out!

```
function PipePair:update(dt)
    if self.x > -PIPE_WIDTH then
        self.x = self.x - PIPE_SCROLL * dt
        self.pipes['lower'].x = self.X
        self.pipes['upper'].x = self.x
    else
        self.remove = true
    end
end
```

There is a capital X on self.pipes['lower'].x = self.X. For so long I have been trying to figure it out and it was all due to an X. Wow, I feel so stupid.

Answer (score 0):

the error is saying that a variable is nil, this might have been caused by a typo. and the problem is being caused because of a capital X in `self.X`

try:

```
function PipePair:update(dt)
    if self.x > -PIPE_WIDTH then
        self.x = self.x - PIPE_SCROLL * dt
        self.pipes['lower'].x = self.x -- typo was here
        self.pipes['upper'].x = self.x
    else
        self.remove = true
    end
end
```